# How to set values in a Pandas DataFrame Column equal to values based on another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames - Final_df and Cust_LCK. In the Final_df DataFrame, I have a column with blank values named "Cust Group" and another column with a unique account number - "Acct #" (the link between the two dataframes). The other DataFrame (Cust_LCK) has a column titled "Acct #" with the unique account number and "Cust Group" with the customer group the account number belongs to.

How do I fill in the blanks in Final_df with the customer groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map values from `Cust_LCK` to `Final_df` column.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

Final_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Acct#'     : range(0, 5),
})

Final_df['Cust Group'] = ''

Cust_LCK = pd.DataFrame({
    'Acct#'     : range(5, 0, -1),
    'Cust Group': range(10, 15)
})

Final_df['Cust Group'] = Final_df['Acct#'].map(Cust_LCK.set_index('Acct#')['Cust Group'])
```

If you have duplicates on values of `Cust_LCK` column, keep only one of them with [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```py
Final_df['Cust Group'] = Final_df['Acct#'].map(Cust_LCK.drop_duplicates(subset['Acct#']).set_index('Acct#')['Cust Group'])
```

If the duplicates rows in `Cust_LCK` has different `Cust Group` values, keep them with [pandas.DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```py
Final_df = Final_df.merge(Cust_LCK[['Acct#', 'Cust Group']], how='left', on=['Acct#']).drop('Cust Group_x', axis=1).rename(columns={'Cust Group_y': 'Cust Group'})
```

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

Final_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Acct#'     : range(0, 5),
})

Final_df['Cust Group'] = ''

print(Final_df)

'''
   Acct# Cust Group
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
'''

Cust_LCK = pd.DataFrame({
    'Acct#'     : [4, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'Cust Group': range(10, 15)
})
Cust_LCK['Group'] = ''


print(Cust_LCK)

'''
   Acct#  Cust Group Group
0      4          10
1      4          11
2      3          12
3      2          13
4      1          14
'''

Final_df = Final_df.merge(Cust_LCK[['Acct#', 'Cust Group']], how='left', on=['Acct#']).drop('Cust Group_x', axis=1).rename(columns={'Cust Group_y': 'Cust Group'})

print(Final_df)

'''
   Acct#  Cust Group
0      0         NaN
1      1        14.0
2      2        13.0
3      3        12.0
4      4        10.0
5      4        11.0
'''
```

If you don't want to drop and rename columns after merge. Drop `Cust Group` column of `Final_df` before merge.

Comment: Didn't work. Threw index error. InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @wleonard It couldn't have this error if the value of `Acct #` is unique.

Comment: @wleonard Edited my answer, see if it satisfies your need.